# Jenkins Perforce Label Sharing across jobs

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, perforce, jenkins-plugins

Is there are a way one can share variables across jenkins jobs ?

Job1 collects the required source code and labels them using perl scripts.
Then a number of other jobs compiles the code since there are many versions. As of now i have made the other jobs depend on Job1 so that same code could be collected from head since it was labelled just before in Job1, but this was not the case during release since codes were going in the repository at odd hours so we had no control, so we thought it would be nice if we could find a way to sync the code using perforce label created in Job1. I did not find any way to sync to particular label that got created in a different job.
So i thought if we could set an environment variable and then use the same for the following jobs, then the codes can be in perfect sync. But seems like environment variables cannot be shared across jobs.

I would appreciate any ideas and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the "Use Upstream Project revision" option? It allows you to sync to the changeset of another project.

If you want to stick to the label idea, I think it's doable. I haven't tried this, but I think I would first have the first job create a new label based on the job name and the build number; both are available in the create label post-build action.

If you launch the downstream job using the paramaterized trigger plugin it will have access to the upstream job name and build number as environment variables. The 'P4 Label' field in the downstream job can then use parameter substitution to specify the correct label name to sync to.

Answer (score 0):

[Perforce plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin) can help you.

Look at section "Sync multiple builds to the same changeset".